# Interpolation of values in a table

Tags: math, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a source array of values that I should interpolate. I need to overwrite selected cells with an interpolation. The interpolation should be calculated from the adjacent cell (linear = more square). The source values are from all 4 sides (top, bottom, left, right). The results array should look as in the picture below. I'm  looking for a mathematical solution, because I need to implement in in pseudo code.

Thanks!

[Source array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbViD.png)
[Results array image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSJRE.png)

Comment: For a mathematical solution direct your search engine at the term *5-point stencil*.  There is a lot of prior art.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define clear rules for this "interpolation". For example, you can use average of four neighbors

```
(100+150+80+32)/4=90.5
```

instead of your value 76

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the rules for it. It is calculated in external software and the provided results are correct.